# How do I solve this binomial(?) probability problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here is the problem:

The time taken, Y seconds to produce a widget using machine B is normally distributed,
with a mean of 10 seconds and a standard deviation of 1.2 seconds. A widget which takes more that 12.2 seconds to produce is considered to be unprofitable. If the probability that m or more widgets in a sample of size 64 from Machine B are unprofitable is less that 0.05%, find the smallest value of m, where m is an integer. The answer given by the textbook is 8, but the textbook provides no reasoning or guides on how to get the answer.

I have attempted to solve the problem with Bernoulli sequence and CAS, but am getting nowhere.

Comment: Have you tried using the Normal distribution to calculate the probability that a given widget is unprofitable?